# Saving pagination position

Tags: backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

I have made a pagination for a list by `Bootstrap` and `Backbone`. The list contains links for different pages. What is the best way to to "save" the pagination "page" when user goes to different page and comes back to page where the pagination is the pagination gets resetted to page one. I can't use hash because there are many bugs with `window.history.back()`. Are there any decisions? Or how can I use `cookies`?

Comment: Are you using a server-side framework? You could store the pagination "page" in session. Although if your paging is not hitting the server, that would require an ajax call to store the current "page" in session. Cookies might be easier. Check out https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: Here's an idea from Dan Hough about [keeping a view's scroll position](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:QtfhLGU0pkUJ:https://danhough.com/blog/backbone-scroll-position/+&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) which could be adapted to keeping any state about the view. I linked to the google cache version because Dan's security cert is currently bogus. I also saw someone suggest creating a Model for each View that's just for the View's state (not the fetched data).

Comment: *"where the pagination is the pagination gets resetted to page one"* - what...? I lost you there

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to use [routing](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/what-is-a-router); When you press the back button from browser you will be redirected to the last route; If you have a custom back button on the page, add on your page model last_page property. When you render the page set the route as url address.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have problem with your application structure. BackboneJS used to write single page. So that, when you choose different page index, your page should not reload, only new data is applied to your table. You should start with this book http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/